# Preguntar antes de cancelar la edición del DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Intento que mi aplicación me pregunte si quiero descartar los cambios antes de que se cancele la edición. Cuando pulso la tecla <kbd>ESC</kbd> se cancela la edición pero nunca se invoca el evento `CancelRowEdit`.

---

*Codigo C#*

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this._dgv.CancelRowEdit += new QuestionEventHandler(this._dgv_CancelRowEdit);
}

private void _dgv_CancelRowEdit(object sender, QuestionEventArgs e) //No se invoca
{
    //La edición se cancela sin importar si `e.Responce` es `true/false`.
    if (QuestionMessage("¿Desea descartar los cambios?") is DialogResult.No) e.Response = false;
    else e.Response = true;
}

private DialogResult QuestionMessage(string m) 
{ 
    return MessageBox.Show(m, "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question); 
}
```

---

**Nota:** Estoy utilizando una clase para manejar el `DataGridView`. Ademas al presionar <kbd>ESC</kbd> se cierra el formulario. *(No tengo ningún evento `keyPress` en el formulario)*. Intente [esto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/db486d50-48f3-405d-bc7a-ad3720d4dd57/datagridview-how-to-capture-a-cells-keypress-event?forum=winformsdatacontrols) y con todos los `KeyEvents` pero tampoco se invocan al presionar <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Si no se puede llamar este evento al presionar <kbd>ESC</kbd> me gustaria saber de que otra forma podría preguntar al usuario si desea descartar los cambios. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Saludos.

---

Gracias a [@Gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) puede arreglar la propiedad del formulario que **causaba que se cerrará el formulario**. Cambiando la propiedad (`CancelButton = none`).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Recompensa:

Ya el metodo se invoca pero a pesar de si elige "**SI** o **NO**" la edición se cancela. ¿De qué forma impido que se cancele la edición si elijo "**NO** *dejar de editar*"?

Comment: Haz proabado QuestionMessage("¿Desea descartar los cambios?") == DialogResult.No ????

Comment: He utilizado el modo debug y nunca se invoca el evento.

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando el DataGridView en "modo virtual" (`VirtualMode=true`)? Sólo en ese caso se utiliza el evento `CancelRowEdit`

Comment: Puse el `VirtualMode=true` y nada.

Comment: No es tan sencillo el modo virtual del DataGridView se utiliza para enlazarlo  a almacenes de datos personalizados. Su implementación es bastante compleja (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx). Si no es tu caso deberás buscar otra forma de realizar lo que quieres sin utilizar ese evento

Comment: Si al presionar esc tu form se cierra es porque esta en modo dialogo y tiene el cancel habilitado por esc. es una propiedad que no recuerdo cual era, por eso se cierra el form.

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi ya no se cierra y el ento se invoca puedes poner tu respuesta para puntuarla.

Comment: En realidad no sabria que contestar.. podrias poner una imagen de las propiedades de tu form, aclarar eso que pasaba en tu pregunta, asi armo una respuesta completa.. y aclara en el titulo que el form se cerraba... asi alguien con el mismo problema lo puede reconocer...

Answer (score 2):

En winforms, un formulario declarado como dialogo tiene una propiedad de cancel en true, que hace que se cierre cuando se presiona ESC.

Esto es una funcionalidad por defecto de los formularios para que se puedan cerrar como dialogos.

Lo que esta pasando en este caso, es que ese evento de cierre del form tiene prioridad sobre el evento de la grilla, y el esc tiene prioridad sobre los eventos de teclado de los controles hijos. Por lo tanto, el evento no se ejecuta y el formulario se cierra.

Comment: La propiedad que me daba problemas era `CancelButton`.

Comment: genial. lo otro que estas viendo no es la propiedad handle. no tiene una propiedad cancel?

Comment: La unica que tiene es `Response` y no se como implementarlo.

Comment: segun la msdn, no podes cancelar este evento como queres hacerlo vos...

Comment: proba poner response on false y decime que pasa.

Comment: ya lo intente y se pierde la edición de todos modos.

Answer (score 2):

La manera que encontré es overridando la función `ProcessCmdKey` en un control que hereda de `DataGridView`:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestGridEditC
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestGridEditC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Prueba");

            dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");
            dt.Columns.Add("Apellido");

            for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add("Nombre" + ii, "Apellido" + ii);
            }

            myDataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

MyDataGridView.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestGridEditC
{
    public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea descartar los cambios?", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jesse-r-jose, te ha servido?

Answer (score 1):

Quizas es un poco tarde, pero te comento que DialogResult tiene varios resultados posibles como Yes, No y Cancel, entre otros, por lo que supongo que solo debes cambiar tu condición para que te quede algo asi

```
 if (QuestionMessage("¿Desea descartar los cambios?") <> DialogResult.Yes)
```

Espero que eso arregle el problema, saludos.

Ahí va el link con el listado completo de valores posibles que retorna DialogResult:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: El problema no esta en el `DilogResoult` ni en la condición `if`.